# Polymorphism ambiguities, can we resolve them with a "default" base to use

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, polymorphism

I need a layer of abstraction involving `QWidget` that can be `QGLWidget`, and I wonder if there is a way to say to the compiler, "Any time you have a doubt (ambiguities) try to use the default base I give you", of course if there is ambiguities it can't resolve with the default choice it prompts errors just like it does. My aim is not have to explicitly solve each of ambiguities one by one since I will always re-direct them to the same class.

Quick setup,

```
#Qt inheritance (very roughly...)
class QWidget {}; 
class QGLWidget : public QWidget {}; 

#my side
class MyAbstract : public QWidget {}; //used by a factory
class MyClass1 : public MyAbstract {}; 
class MyClass2 : public MyAbstract, public QGLWidget{};
```

I'am aware compiler can't determine by its-self witch duplicated methods to use for the `MyClass2` class, since `QGLwidget` inherits and re-implement most of the `QWidget`, but can I tell to the complier to use `QGLWidget` first since I know that's what I want ?

Qt is just an example here.

Comment: What are you trying to model with the multiple inheritance here? Does `MyAbstract` really need to be a child of `QWidget`?

Comment: Let say the factory or any other class aware of what 'MyAbstract' is, what to call 'QWidget' level methods like 'update()' or worth want to connect some to one of its signals ... kind of pain full to re-implement everywhere. Be sure I don't have just 2 class that inherits of 'MyAbstract', otherwise I tried to avoid the 'QWidget' base :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally doubt that this kind of automatic disambiguation is feasible in C++ at the language level.

What is possible is, case-by-case, disambiguate by explicitly giving the class whose method should be executed, like this:

```
QGLWidget::ambiguous_method(...
```

This is not what you are asking for, I know, and I am sure you already know about it. I am saying just for completeness.

On another hand, I am not sure that this kind of automatic disambiguation would be desirable or simply helpful, because the main point about multiple inheritance being "delicate" is the replication of data inside of the derived class. If you had automatic disambiguation, you would end up using sometimes (when there is no ambiguity) the partial object corresponding to a base class, and in other cases the partial object corresponding to the other base class (because of automatic disambiguation) and you would get a mosaic of things that would not make any sense, i.e. a corrupt object...

Finally, I think that this kind of automatic disambiguation would be infeasible in case you have more complex inheritance diagrams, like, following your example:

```
class Nasty : QGLWidget {};

class Very_nasty : Nasty, MyClass2 {};
```

There would be no possibility of automatic disambiguation. Indeed, say that the classes you provided form a library and that you decided, when building the library, to use `MyClass2::QGLWidget` as a base for disambiguation.

Now, I take your library and define two more classes like the ones I gave. `Very_nasty` inherits `QGLWidget` from `Nasty` and from `Class2`; each one has got a `QGWidget` inside, and overall I have 3 of them (because Class2 already inherited it twice).

Now suppose that for me, a base class for disambiguation should be `Very_Nasty::Nasty::QGLWidget`, given the semantics of my class. If you say that automatic disambiguation is a way to resolve ambiguities with multiple inheritance, I should be able to specify it with each case of multiple inheritance.

What would happen if I call through `Very_nasty` a method inherited from MyClass2?

What would happen if I call through `Very_nasty` a method inherited from Nasty?

They would take two different disambiguation paths. Clash.

Comment: Thank for the completeness, but yes that's what I tried to avoid, I did it for the `QWidget` level ... it was long ... when gcc start to complain about some `OQbject` method, I gave-up !

Comment: @sergio: that the kind of information I am looking for, cause if we cannot do it there must be a reason ... but again can't I do this mosaic by myself one method at a time?

Comment: @vrince: yeah, you can... you can do many things by yourself with C++, the point is that with the automatic disambiguation, this mosaic-ization would get out of your control... anyway I added one more thought... :-)

Comment: @sergio:to be honest, don't really understand your last point.

Comment: @sergio: in my view your are exposing the problem a second time, and here again unless you specify the "path" your want to use the complier won't choose it by its-self. The only known part is `MyClass2` inherits from `QWidget` through 'QGLWidget' is you introduce an other 'QWidget' you have to deal with it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer: don't model anything as inheritance until it's absolutely necessary.

Exact answer: use virtual base class.

Comment: How in this case virtual base class can helps ? (not a sarcastic question even if it sound like one :) ). Remember I don't want to touch QWidget or QGLWidget, all I know is QGLWidget::QWidget.

Comment: Well, you're right. What you're trying to achieve is broken by design. Stick to "good answer" then :)

Comment: I knew back then (before asking) this wasn't possible "by design", I'am just looking for the goods reasons to stop thinking it could be useful ...

Comment: Just read C++ FQA about multiple inheritance: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/inheritance-multiple.html Multiple inheritance in C++ is itself broken by design. There is no sane reason to use it.

Comment: Actually occasionally multiple inheritance has a justifiable use for mixins, but in general it's not good.